Why does this code keep returning "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 48 out of bounds for length 48"?
This method was supposed to separate an array 'playlist1d' at every '|' and then send them into the 2d array 'playlist2d' but it keeps returning the same error each time.
    public String[][] charCounterRow(int songCount, String[] playlist1d)throws IOException{
        Character temp;
        int characterCount=0, col = 0, rowLength, nullCount=0;
        String playlist2d[][] = new String[lineCount][6];
        String tempLine = "|", tempString;
        for(int counter = 0; counter < lineCount; counter++){
            temp = playlist1d[counter].charAt(characterCount);
            tempString = String.valueOf(temp);
            rowLength = playlist1d[counter].length();
            while(characterCount < rowLength && col <= 5){
                if(tempString.equals(tempLine)){
                    characterCount++;
                    col++;
                    nullCount = 0;
                    temp = playlist1d[counter].charAt(characterCount);
                    tempString = String.valueOf(temp);
                }
                else if(!tempString.equals(tempLine)){
                    if(nullCount == 0){
                        playlist2d[counter][col] = String.valueOf(temp);
                    }
                    else{
                        playlist2d[counter][col] += temp;
                    }
                    characterCount++;
                    temp = playlist1d[counter].charAt(characterCount);
                    tempString = String.valueOf(temp);
                    nullCount++;
                }
            }
            characterCount = 0;
            col=0;
        }
        return playlist2d;
    }

The problem keeps occuring in the line "temp = playlist1d[counter].charAt(characterCount);" under the first 'if' statement. I tried fixing it by adding the 'col<=5' within the while loop but for some reason the code block within it keeps running even though col exceeds 5
Here's the text in the array:
This should be under playlist1d
 private static String[] playlist1d = new String[] {
            "List | Title | Artist | Album | Genre | Rating | ",
            "1 | qwer | asd | zxcv | asdf | 2 | ",
            "2 | wert | sdfg | xcvb | sfdg | 3 | ",
            "3 | erty | dfgh | cvbn | dfgh | 1 | ",
            "4 | qwer | asdf | zxcv | sedfg | 5 | ",
            "5 | wert | sdf | asdf | qwer | 4 | ",
            "6 | poij | wert | asdf | bsfs | 4 | ",
            "7 | test | fdsf | gfddg | oij | 4 | ",
            "8 | tret | gfgd | sdfd | we | 1 | ",
            "9 | t | s | d | f | 4 | ",
            "10 | poij | wert | sdfgshdg | a | 2 | ",
            "11 | qer | asdaf | tsth | sf | ",
            "12 | qwer | asdf | zxcv | asfd | 2 |"
    };

lineCount and songCount would both be just the amount of rows in the array or 13 in this case.
I expected the code under the while loop to just stop after the 'col' variable goes past 5 but for some reason it goes until 6, then the error pops up. I also tried making it col < 5 in the while loop and that works and limits col to 4, but it just wouldn't work for col < 6 or col <=5.

Can you please provide sample values for int songCount, String[] playlist1d and int lineCount?

Length 48 means indexes go from 0 to 47. 48 is out of bounds...

I understand that 48 is out of bounds but i'm not too sure how it gets to 48 in the first place. In the while loop I have it so the rowlength is 48, so i thought it would just stop at 47 or if it reaches 5 columns

@Michael How are you calculating lineCount (I think you answered this in part, but your answer appears to have been deleted).

Oh, I see -- by inference -- that it's likely playlist1d.length.

@tresf I just put lineCount as a global variable and I edit it throughout the code so long as I change the number of lines in the array.

You're incrementing and using the new value before that bounds check is returned to, so you're essentially bound to run over your bounds this way.

FYI, another potential bug: Track 11 is missing a rating value.

You're trying to access a character at rowLength. You ensure characterCount is less than rowLength, but then increment characterCount++ just before use.
One solution is to stop looping at rowLength -1, so that characterCount never exceeds your array size.
Before:
rowLength = playlist1d[counter].length();

After:
rowLength = playlist1d[counter].length() - 1;

This way the statement temp = playlist1d[counter].charAt(characterCount); doesn't try to access an element greater than its own size (the classic "index starts at zero" problem).
Another solution is to move your incrementation until after you use the index, but this may affect other logic.
Unrelated, but I find myself using String.split() in times like this to avoid tracking each character.  It may require more processing power than your solution, but is often easier to read and debug.

Thank you so much man it finally works. This index stuff is always so annoying and I always get mixed up with it since it starts with 0. Honestly I wish I could use that String.split() function since it sounds pretty useful for this kind of application but unfortunately I'm limited to just the concepts I've learned in that class so :/

Great, if you found the answer to fix your problem, you may mark it as solved.

Uhh how exactly do you resolve the post

@Michael usually there's a checkbox under the up and down arrows to mark as resolved.  You may also, if you wish, upvote any questions or answers that you find useful on the website.

Okay thanks I clicked the checkmark and I would upvote but unfortunately I need 15 reputation first. This was definitely helpful though!
